What does Srila Bhaktisiddhanta Thakur mean by Swarupa?
In the Bhāgavatam commentary(Vivṛti on Bhāg. 11.2.37), Śrīla Bhaktisiddhānta wrote,
Advaya-jñāna vrajendra-nandana svayaṁ-rūpa tattva. Tadāśrita janagaṇera sva-svarūpe avasthiti-kāle kona apriya vṛti āvāhana karibāra avakāśa haya nā.
“Vrajendra-nandana, the non-dual consciousness, is the svayam-rūpa tattva. Those who have taken shelter of Him, being situated in their own svarūpa, have no opportunity to invoke any kind of inauspiciousness.”
What does being in own svarupa mean?

Svarupa is one's constitutional position (servant of Krishna), which is the same as siddha deha.
